# How to get all values out of the prepared statement query result

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have next code, to create mysqli object and to prepare query:

```
    $GLOBALS['DB_something'] = new mysqli('$database_hostname','$database_username','$database_password','$database_default');
    $GLOBALS['DB_prepared_get'] = $GLOBALS['DB_something']->prepare("SELECT ? from database_name WHERE hash=?");
```

and next code, to get and display the results. Since I haven't been into prepared statements recently, specialy not with PHP, im not sure how to get the results out of it.

When i wrote the code without prepared statements, it works, but for many reasons, I need to rewrite it with prepared statements.

```
$GLOBALS['DB_prepared_get']->bind_param('ss', $arg, $index);
$GLOBALS['DB_prepared_get']->execute();
$GLOBALS['DB_prepared_get']->bind_result($result); # this is an array of values 

$GLOBALS['DB_prepared_get']->fetch();       
            # below this, I don't know if it's ok               
            if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0){
                return "0";
            }

            else{
                while($GLOBALS['DB_prepared_get']->fetch()) {
                    return $result;
                }
            }

            $GLOBALS['DB_prepared_get']->close();
```

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: just to be clear, my problem is how to fetch the exact result values to print them out or something. So syntax is what I am probably doing wrong.

Comment: What is on the select, the prepared statement doesn't works for the first ? parameter if i am not mistaken, you have to write it explicitly

Comment: what's the point of having a prepared statement than? :(

Comment: Security sometimes performance, what you will change is the values like, SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=? , and you use the ? for the multiples Ids

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't specify the columns of a query as a parameter. You would have to write the columns directly in the prepared statement string.

Something like

```
$GLOBALS['DB_prepared_get'] = $GLOBALS['DB_something']->prepare("SELECT a,b,c from database_name WHERE hash=?");
```

Comment: with direct columns in prepared statements, my 'prepared statement' is not useful anymore, is it?

Comment: Well the idea of prepared statements is to validate and clean input parameters(among other things). Which it is very useful for.

Comment: and the most important-the query is ready only once. later, only parameters are changed. and thats why i need to change SELECT X this X with bindParam later.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many faults in your code that I not even try to explain whats wrong with it. I can say however, that if you are not experienced in OO programming, you first should try to write the procedural code with mysqli.

This code should work:

```
  $mysqli = new mysqli( $database_hostname, $database_username, $database_password, $database_default );
  if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '  . $mysqli->connect_error);

  if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT ? from database_name WHERE hash=?")) {
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $fieldname); // first marker
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $hashwhere); // second marker

    $stmt->execute();

    $result = array();
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
      $result[] = array($fieldname);
    }

    $stmt->close();
  }

  $mysqli->close();

  var_dump($result);
```

Comment: this doesn't work as well. But I'm usign $GLOBALS to put in the $stmt, because that's my case and can't do it without using it.